# Pocket sphinx and virtual assistant

Tags: python-3.x, pocketsphinx

I am trying to do a virtual assistant as my major project. So I want to install pocket sphinx package to run this offline. If anyone know this please answer to this.

Comment: Hello, please go through on how to ask a question on stackoverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. And edit your question based on that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I thing you are using pocketsphinx for speech to text conversion. If its so pocketsphinx package used to convert speech into text(offline as well) in Python.
Below comments is used to installing the packages.

```
pip install SpeechRecognition
conda install swig
pip install pocketsphinx
```

Once Installing pocketsphinx you may get the error like "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/ please install "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0" then do "**pip install pocketsphinx**" Once installed the above packages you can start testing some "**.wav**" file for speech to text conversion.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
AUDIO_FILE='C:\\Users\\Downloads\\test.wav'
    
r=sr.Recognizer()
with sr.AudioFile(AUDIO_FILE) as source:
    audio=r.record(source)
text=r.recognize_sphinx(audio)
with open("result.txt","w") as text_file:
    text_file.write(format(text))
```